# Android Studio: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal

I have a very common problem, but I tried already to fix it and it doesn't work.

This is my SDK location:
[image]

I added that path to Environment Variables 
[image]

[image]

I also tried just "D:\Stuff\Program Files (x86)\Android". 
It doesn't work.
[image]

What works is this though:

[image]

What can I do to use just 'adb' command?

PS: This doesn't happen just for 'adb'. 'emulator -list-avds' or something doesn't work as well.
Thanks for your time spent here.